# Summary of differences in regular expression syntax for various tools and languages?

Tags: regex, grep

I can never remember the differences in regular expression syntax used by tools like [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), or languages like Python and PHP. Generally, Perl has the most expansive syntax, but I'm often hamstrung by the limitations of even `egrep` ("extended" `grep`).

Is there a site that lists the differences in a concise and easy-to-read fashion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124), devotes the last four chapters to Java, PHP, Perl, and [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).  One chapter for each. From what I know, the [pocket edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514271) contains just those final four chapters.

Answer (score 11):

For my own future reference, I'll offer the [Regexp Syntax Summary](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html) page which contrasts the syntax for `grep`, `egrep`, Emacs, Perl, Python, and Tcl. As expected, Perl supports the greatest variety of operators, but Python looks equally capable, if not more so.

Answer (score 5):

I find this site helpful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Other than that, I use the corresponding documentation extensively and I believe, all said and done, there's no way around that.